# Division value casted to double with tricks in parentheses

Tags: java, casting, double, division

The following code with presence and absence of parentheses produce different output. Why?

```
System.out.println((double) 3/6);    // output 0.5

System.out.println((double) (3/6));  // output 0.0
```

Comment: Integer division gets everybody the first time.

Answer (score 2):

Because in the first example you are actually doing `((double) 3)/6`, and therefore the result is a double too.

In the second one, you are performing an integer division, and then you are casting the result. `3/6 = 0`, and `(double) 0 = 0.0`.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, you are casting 3 to a double before dividing by an int. According the Java type conversion rules, the output is a double(0.5 in this case).

In the second example, you are dividing an int by an int. Since the number you are dividing is smaller than the number you are dividing with, the answer is zero. Then you are simply casting int 0 to double 0.